# Using jQuery to replace a class that is adjacent to another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, replace, conditional-statements

I am trying to use jQuery to replace a class that is adjacent to another class.

I cannot just simply replace the class, as the same class is used under different circumstances, and I need to replace them with different classes.

An example is easier to display.

```
<div class="cancel button button-primary>
<div class="next button button-primary>
<div class="prev button button-primary>
<div class="send button button-primary>
```

What I need to replace is `button-primary`, but replace it with a different class depending on another class, namely `cancel`, `next`, `prev` and `send`.

The result would need to be:

```
<div class="cancel button button-red>
<div class="next button button-blue>
<div class="prev button button-grey>
<div class="send button button-green>
```

If I use this code:

`jQuery('.target_element').removeClass('button-primary').addClass('button-red');`

It would replace ALL instances of `button-primary` with `button-red`. That is not the goal.

How can I set up a conditional script that would replace `button-primary` with the relevant class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
$('div.button').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('cancel')){
    $(this).removeClass('button-primary')
    $(this).addClass('button-red')
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('next')){
    $(this).removeClass('button-primary')
    $(this).addClass('button-blue')
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('prev')){
    $(this).removeClass('button-primary')
    $(this).addClass('button-grey')
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('send')){
    $(this).removeClass('button-primary')
    $(this).addClass('button-green')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cancel button button-primary">
<div class="next button button-primary">
<div class="prev button button-primary">
<div class="send button button-primary">
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case:

```
jQuery('.target_element').removeClass('button-primary').addClass('button-red');
```

`target_element` would be a unique class, so that its changes can be applied to that one element only like:

```
jQuery('.cancel').removeClass('button-primary').addClass('button-red');
```

here only one `cancel` class is present in a page. Or use `#` i.e. Id selector instead of class selector

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('.button').removeClass('button-primary');
$('.cancel').addClass('button-red');
$('.next').addClass('button-blue');
$('.prev').addClass('button-grey');
$('.send').addClass('button-green');
```

this might be the shortest way, unless you have many more of these situations, then you can set up an array of combinations and use a loop.

Comment: *"this might be the shortest way"* - it might be the **longest** way. Anyways, always try to avoid hard coded solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) which has to return the class that should be added.

```js
var mapping = {
  "cancel": "red",
  "next": "blue",
  "prev": "grey",
  "send": "green"
};
  
$(".button-primary")
  .addClass(function(_, classes) {
      var relevantClass = classes.split(" ").shift();
      return mapping[relevantClass] || "";
    })
  .removeClass("button-primary");
```

```css
.button-primary { font-style: italic }
.red { color: red }
.blue { color: blue }
.grey { color: grey }
.green { color: green }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cancel button button-primary">cancel</div>
<div class="next button button-primary">next</div>
<div class="prev button button-primary">prev</div>
<div class="send button button-primary">send</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the dependencies inside e.g. an object and then just refer to it, while operating over each element with `button` class.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('button'),
    obj = {cancel: 'button-red', next: 'button-blue', prev: 'button-grey', send: 'button-green'};
    
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(v) {
      var elem = document.querySelector("." + v);
      elem.classList.remove('button-primary');
      elem.classList.add(obj[v]);
    })
    
    console.log(Array.from(elems));
```

```html
<div class="cancel button button-primary">
<div class="next button button-primary">
<div class="prev button button-primary">
<div class="send button button-primary">
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all `.button-primary` element and use [`addClass( function )`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to adding new class to selected element. In callback function add your condition and return your target new class. After adding new class remove old class using `.removeClass()`

```js
$(".button-primary").addClass(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("cancel"))
    return "button-red";
  else if ($(this).hasClass("next"))
    return "button-blue";
  else if ($(this).hasClass("prev"))
    return "button-gray";
  else if ($(this).hasClass("send"))
    return "button-green";
}).removeClass("button-primary");
```

```css
.button-red {color: red}
.button-blue {color: blue}
.button-gray {color: gray}
.button-green {color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cancel button button-primary">cancel</div>
<div class="next button button-primary">next</div>
<div class="prev button button-primary">prev</div>
<div class="send button button-primary">send</div>
```